# How to use a variable to set the root log level in logback.xml?

Tags: logging, logback

I am trying to use an environment variable, `ROOT_LOG_LEVEL`, to control the root log level for a project that uses a `logback.xml` configuration file.

```
<configuration>
  <!-- You can override these with environment variables -->
  <variable name="ROOT_LOG_LEVEL" value="$ROOT_LOG_LEVEL:-INFO" />
  <variable name="EXAMPLE_LOG_LEVEL" value="$EXAMPLE_LOG_LEVEL:-INFO" />

  <logger name="com.example" level="$EXAMPLE_LOG_LEVEL" />

  <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%level - %message</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <root level="$ROOT_LOG_LEVEL">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
  </root>

</configuration>
```

With this configuration, I can set the log level for package `com.example` by either setting the environment variable (e.g. `EXAMPLE_LOG_LEVEL=TRACE`), or by not setting the variable and falling back to the default `INFO`.

While this works for `com.example`, it does not work for the root logger. When I try to use a variable in `level="$ROOT_LOG_LEVEL"`, it falls back to the internal default `DEBUG` regardless of the contents of the variable. Only if I replace `$ROOT_LOG_LEVEL` by an explicit value like `INFO`, the root logger is changed.

Is there a way to set the root log level based on a variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, the answer to my question is that Logback does not accept variables like this:

```
<variable name="ROOT_LOG_LEVEL" value="$ROOT_LOG_LEVEL:-INFO" />
<root level="$ROOT_LOG_LEVEL">
```

Instead, use:

```
<variable name="ROOT_LOG_LEVEL" value="${ROOT_LOG_LEVEL:-INFO}" />
<root level="${ROOT_LOG_LEVEL}">
```

That works! Note that the `:-INFO` must be inside the braces.

Comment: Just using `<root level="${LOGBACK_LOG_LEVEL:-INFO}">` and omitting the `<variable .../>` stuff also worked for me.

Comment: im trying to use it for application packaage level, not at root level.
    <logger name="com.app" level="${APP_LOG_LEVEL:-INFO}" additivity="false">
the logs are not printted based on environment variable